# Show a popup message after completion of WorkFlow 4 from the controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I am a beginner in WorkFlow 4 (WF 4), I am running through a serious issue using it in MVC 3, I couldn't find the answer online.

I need to show a popup message if an exception occurred in the workFlow or anything returned in the outpput arguments, I have a page that the user would edit and at the end he will click Save button.

Clicking the Save button will submit the form to the controller and run a workflow, when the workflow completed, I got an output explaining if updating the data through the workflow succeeded or not, then I need to show this status on completed action, but I am unable to since I run it asynchronously which means the method will return to the user and in parallel the workflow is invoking the event.

Here is my code in the controller:

```
[HttpPost()]
    public ActionResult SaveVehicles(vehiclesData model) {
   Services.VehiclesDataUpdate vehiclesDataUpdate = new Services.VehiclesDataUpdate(this.SessionData.DealerLotKey, null, null);
            IDictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            parameters.Add("VehiclesDataUpdate", vehiclesDataUpdate);
            parameters.Add("UnionVehicles", unionVehicles);
            parameters.Add("SolrVehicles", solrVehicles);

            IDictionary<string, object> outputs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            AutoResetEvent syncEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            WorkflowApplication wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(new VehiclesUpdate(), parameters);

            wfApp.Completed = delegate(WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs e) {
                outputs = e.Outputs;
                 syncEvent.Set();

                if (!errorExceptions.IsNullOrEmpty()) {
                    //TODO: Render a parital view to display an error message or the result of the workflow in the ouptput
                    //TODO: Logging.
                }
            };

            wfApp.Aborted = delegate(WorkflowApplicationAbortedEventArgs e) {
                syncEvent.Set();
            };

            wfApp.Run();

 return View(model);
    }
```

How can I send something back to the user when workflow completion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [WorkflowInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowinvoker.aspx) or use a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) to signal to the ASP.NET worker thread that the workflow application has completed execution.

Comment: Would you provide me an example?

Comment: There are plenty here.  Troll through [wf4] and read.  I won't answer, as I believe there might be a better solution by using [asynchronous pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx) in ASP.NET.  The problem is that I'm nowhere near familiar enough with this in order to give an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a workflow from an MVC action there are several ways you can do so. First fo all you can use the WorkflowApplication as you did. I have adapted the code to use an AyncController that is a better fit with a WorkflowApplication.

```
public class HomeController : AsyncController
{
    [HttpPost()]
    public void SaveVehiclesAsync(vehiclesData model)
    {
        Services.VehiclesDataUpdate vehiclesDataUpdate = new Services.VehiclesDataUpdate(this.SessionData.DealerLotKey, null, null);
        IDictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters.Add("VehiclesDataUpdate", vehiclesDataUpdate);
        parameters.Add("UnionVehicles", unionVehicles);
        parameters.Add("SolrVehicles", solrVehicles);

        WorkflowApplication wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(new VehiclesUpdate(), parameters);

        wfApp.Completed = delegate(WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs e) {
            AsyncManager.Parameters["outputs"] = e.Outputs;
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
        };

        wfApp.Aborted = delegate(WorkflowApplicationAbortedEventArgs e) {
           AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
        };

        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
        wfApp.Run();
    }

    public ActionResult IndexCompleted(IDictionary<string, object> outputs)
    {
        var model = outputs["model"];
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

However that might not always be the best solution.  In general an ASP.NET server is going to be busy enough to keep all cores happy so asynchronous processing is only going to hurt scale ability. Now if your workflow is doing mainly async IO this is fine but if it is doing synchronous IO or processing it might be better to use a WorkflowInvoker instead.

The code would be something like this.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost()]
    public ActionResult SaveVehicles(vehiclesData model)
    {
        Services.VehiclesDataUpdate vehiclesDataUpdate = new Services.VehiclesDataUpdate(this.SessionData.DealerLotKey, null, null);
        IDictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters.Add("VehiclesDataUpdate", vehiclesDataUpdate);
        parameters.Add("UnionVehicles", unionVehicles);
        parameters.Add("SolrVehicles", solrVehicles);

        IDictionary<string, object> outputs = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(new VehiclesUpdate(), parameters);

        var model = outputs["model"];
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Note: Did the code with just Notepad++ so be aware of small syntax errors.

Comment: @Mautice: First of all, thank you so much for the answer, it opened my eyes about many things.I am doing the asynchronous way.I understand now how it works but the SaveVehiclesAsync() is a void method which won't return anything, in my case I want to return something to the user while the workflow is processing then when the workflow completes I will return a different thing to the user. How could I implement SaveVehiclesAsync() to return the view for example before the workflow completed.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://encosia.com/easy-incremental-status-updates-for-long-requests/) post for a way to send updates to the browser while the server process is still active.

Comment: Another thing, shouldn't this workflow runs asynchronously and independently, if the workflow is taking time to finish and I tried to go to a different page, it will not go until the workflow is done, is this right?

Comment: No. As far as the browser is concerned you are just aborting a request and stating a new one. There is nothing the server can do to prevent that, only come client side JavaScript can help there.

Comment: So are you saying that if the job is taking 40 seconds to get done and the user wants to navigate to a different page, he should wait until the job is done???

Comment: No, the opposite. You can't stop him from navigating to another page after 1 second.

Comment: Well,  if I set  [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)], I would be able to navigate to a different page while the workflow is still running, what are the limitations for making the session is readonly? did that mean that the current controller cant update the session or the navigated to page cant?